# how to put validation for certain empty textbox

Tags: c#

How can i put validation for txtPName and txtAddress if they are empty i cannot proceed to submit and a messagebox will pop up.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO patientdb.addpatient(PatientName,MobileNumber,Occupation,Gender,Address,Age,PhoneNumber,MedicalHistory,ChiefComplaint) VALUES ('" + txtPName.Text + "','" + txtMNum.Text + "','" + txtOccup.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtAge.Text + "','" + txtPNum.Text + "','" + rtbMHistory.Text + "','" + rtbCC.Text + "')";
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, con);

        try
        {
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
                txtPName.Text = "";
                txtMNum.Text = "";
                txtPNum.Text = "";
                txtAddress.Text = "";
                txtAge.Text = "";
                txtOccup.Text = "";
                rtbMHistory.Text = "";
                rtbCC.Text = "";
                comboBox1.Text = " ";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Not Inserted");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you mean just a simple if before submitting?

Comment: You're already using one `if` statement, so you must know how to write another one.  Right?  So what's the problem?

Comment: i tried the If condition

Comment: What was your `if` condition?

Comment: i tried the if condition 
if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPName.Text))

Comment: sorry if this is such a dumb question im just a beginner who is trying to self study and sometimes i cannot really understand everything in youtube and internet

Comment: That clearly won't work because you're validating *after* you run the query.

Comment: that's what i want to know on how to properly use it, where and when

Comment: In the future, when you have trouble with code, show us the code that gave you trouble.  Don't omit it entirely.  That way we can explain why it didn't work.  It's hard to do that when we have no idea what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a validation check before executing the rest of the code. Calling `return` will immediately leave the method after validation fails.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing Data");
        return;
    }

// Your code here...
```

Comment: thanks for this i added con.Close(); before the return because i get an error that says connection is already open when i tried to input new one, but thankyou for the answer now i understand